# Calling jQuery functions by reference

Tags: jquery

My code is this:

```
$('button#submit-order').on('click', () => orderPanelInfo.hide());
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do same operation like this:

```
$('button#submit-order').on('click', orderPanelInfo.hide);
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't work in Chrome 63 and Firefox 57. Using jQuery v1.11. No messages, no error, I don't have any clue.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing (the arrow function) is fine provided the browsers you're targeting support them (otherwise, just use a normal function). The other alternative is to use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) but it involves repeating yourself:

```
$('button#submit-order').on('click', orderPanelInfo.hide.bind(orderPanelInfo));
// -----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`Function#bind` was added in 2009 so only Really Truly Obsolete browsers have JavaScript engines that don't have it (and it can be polyfilled on them if necessary).

Comment: Yes it works. I was thinking there's a simplier way to do this kind of operation.

Comment: @LuísAssunção: Not really. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work